# Looking for a diode with PJ423K1V marking code

Tags: diodes

I'm looking for a diode on a PC mainboard. The marking code is PJ423K1V. Do you know what is the part number of this component?

The case seems to be a SMA case.

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The package and markings match with a [Panjit P4SMAJ20A](https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/P4SMAJ_SERIES.pdf) TVS diode.
[image]

[LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/TVS_PANJIT-International-P4SMAJ20A_R1_00001_C391566.html) has pictures. Since the upper code isn't explained in the datasheet, I suspect it's a lot number and/or date code.
[image]