# Looking for diode with BV 4GISB marking code

Tags: diodes

Im looking for marking code for the diode for my laptop.
it's same thing and same function in the same motherboard  like PJ423K.diode.
May be give little diference ?
Thak you for yor help
Best Regards

Comment: Please post pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a [SMBJ20CA](https://www.lcsc.com/search?q=SMBJ20CA) TVS diode.

[image]

[image]

The datasheet excerpt and the picture are from the [Brightking](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2111302030_Brightking-SMBJ20CA-TR13_C2926836.pdf) version, but there are many other manufacturers that also use the BV marking and a 4 character date code. Without a picture it's impossible to tell which one you have or if this even is the correct part in the first place.

Edit: Btw the `PJ423K` marking on the other diode is just a date/lot code, see this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670116/looking-for-a-diode-with-pj423k1v-marking-code) as reference.